# What is incorrect with the setTimeout logic used by request limiter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, throttling, rate-limiting

I am trying to simulate HTTP-request throttling with the following code. (Inside step 2)

I want to queue the request if the request is made in less than 300 milliseconds. Later I need to dequeue but keeping the same constraint of 300 milliseconds while making requests.

The code works fine, but I am somewhere incorrect in the dequeue logic. I am unable to keep the constraint of 300 milliseconds during the dequeue process. Sometimes, the difference between `lastRequestMade` and `now` is less than 300 ms, when the set timeout was set to `300 + x`. What could be the reason for this?

```
const moment = require('moment');
const crypto = require('crypto');

let lastRequestMade = null;
let queue = [];
let requestIdList = [];
let lastRequestEq = null;
let timeoutInterval = 0;

// STEP 1
for (let x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    // Init the request queue with the request ids
    requestIdList.push(crypto.randomBytes(8).toString('hex'));
}

// STEP 2 
for (let x = 0; x < 100; x++) {

    if (lastRequestMade && moment().diff(lastRequestMade) < 300) { // Rate limit to 300 milliseconds 
        // If the last request made was less than 300 milliseconds
        // queue the request
        queue.push(requestIdList[x]);
        console.log(`Enqueue ${requestIdList[x]}`);

        timeoutInterval += 300;

        setTimeout(() => {
            let rid = queue.splice(0, 1);
            sendRequest(...rid);
            if (queue.length == 0)
                console.log('No request left in the queue');
        }, timeoutInterval);

    } else {
        sendRequest(requestIdList[x]);
    }
}

/**
 * Request maker
 */
function sendRequest(requestId) {
    if (lastRequestMade && moment().diff(lastRequestMade) < 300)
        console.log('Attempted before 300 ms', moment().diff(lastRequestMade));
    // Make a request
    lastRequestMade = moment();
    console.log(`Request with ${requestId} made !!`);
}
```

There are some requests that are made in less than 300 seconds. I delay each request using `setTimeout` and have kept the multiplying factor equal to the current queue length.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? You can just use something like [`lodash.throttle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.throttle).

Comment: @MarkoGrešak Yeah, I know. There are many libraries there. But I really want to understand this